# Lead-Acid Battery charger circuit

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I designed this charger circuit and I really appreciate any hints or advices so I can modify it and choose right components values.

I'm charging a 6V 4Ah Lead-Acid battery.

[image: Lead-Acid battery charger circuit]

Comment: You already made it; so what's the issue?  Does it take too long to charge, not charge fully, draw too much current, does something break, etc...  As it is now, it's a bit too vague

Comment: I'm not sure about the source voltage.
do i need a current limiting diode between source and battery?
will the over charge protection part work.
any advices about method of choosing values.
thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you charging a 3-cell battery as is in the circuit?  What's it's capacity, etc.  [Edit your question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/71949/edit) to add this information.

Comment: EDITING Done :)

Comment: @NickT I don't think he built it already; rather, he designed the circuit. You can't build it with no part values whatsoever, so it isn't a complete design yet.

Comment: @Kaz that's what I figured...I was associating "made" with physical (versus "drew" or "designed" for the abstract/capture).  Probably reading too much into word choice, that :P

Comment: I'm sorry it is all my fault. 
so i will re edit the question .